# Add "uniqueness" constraint to Decorator Pattern in Java

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns, decorator

I am trying to make some pizza with the Decorator Pattern (bear with me):

Suppose I have the following:

```
interface Pizza {
  public String makePizza();
}
class PlainPizza implements Pizza {
  @Override
  public String makePizza() {
    return "Base Pizza";
  }
}
```

And then I have a general decorator:

```
abstract class PizzaDecorator implements Pizza {

  protected Pizza specialPizza;

  public PizzaDecorator(Pizza specialPizza) {
    this.specialPizza = specialPizza;
  }

  public String makePizza() {
    return specialPizza.makePizza();
  }
}
```

And two implementations of the decorator:

```
class SausageDecorator extends PizzaDecorator {

  public SausageDecorator(Pizza specialPizza) {
    super(specialPizza);
  }

  public String makePizza() {
    return specialPizza.makePizza() + addSausage();
  }

  private String addSausage() {
    return " + sausage";
  }
}
class OliveDecorator extends PizzaDecorator {

  public OliveDecorator(Pizza specialPizza) {
    super(specialPizza);
  }

  public String makePizza() {
    return specialPizza.makePizza() + addOlives();
  }

  private String addOlives() {
    return " + olives";
  }
}
```

The problem is that I am able to have duplicate decorators.

How can I change the structure of this code to add a "uniqueness" constraint - that is, each Decorator can appear as most once? (My pizza place doesn't allow customers to get double sausage, sorry!)

```
class PizzaMaker
    {
        public static void main (String[] args)
        {
            Pizza pizza = new SausageDecorator(new SausageDecorator(new OliveDecorator(new PlainPizza())));
            System.out.println(pizza.makePizza());
        }
    }
```

> Output: Base Pizza + olives + sausage + sausage

Comment: I'm just trying to learn the decorator pattern.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to add unique constraint, you could define an `interface` called `UniqueTopping` like :

```
public interface UniqueTopping {
   public String getTopping();
   public void addTopping();
}
```

and have your decorator classes, `PlainPizza` class implement it.

In your decorator class, have a private variable called `topping` and implement the `getTopping()`, `addTopping()` like below:

```
class SausageDecorator extends PizzaDecorator implements UniqueTopping {

  private String topping = "";

  public SausageDecorator(Pizza specialPizza) {
    super(specialPizza);
  }

  public String makePizza() {
    addTopping();
    return specialPizza.makePizza() + " " + getTopping();
  }

  @Override
  public String getTopping() {
    return topping;
  }

  @Override
  public void addTopping() {

     if ( !specialPizza.getTopping().equals(getTopping()) ) {
         topping = "sausage";
     }

  }

}
```

See that `addTopping()` adds only if the `specialPizza` that is passed in the constructor has a different `topping`.
The `getTopping()` just returns the `topping` that was added in `addTopping()`.

Also your `PlainPizza` should implement the `UniqueTopping` to return empty `topping` like below:

```
class PlainPizza implements Pizza, UniqueTopping {
  @Override
  public String makePizza() {
    return "Base Pizza";
  }

  @Override
  public String getTopping() {
    return "";
  }

  @Override
  public void addTopping() {

  }

}
```